# Merge sort c++ code returns same order of numbers and does not sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

Code:

```
// Merge sort
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void Merge(int *A, int *B1, int one, int *B2, int two){
    int *combi = new int[one+two];
    int c = 0, d = 0, x=0;
    while(c < one && d < two){
        cout<<"B1[C] "<<B1[c]<<" B2[d] "<<B2[d]<<endl;
        if(B1[c] < B2[d]){
            combi[x] = B1[c];
            cout<<"combi[x] = "<<combi[x]<<endl;
            c++;
        }
        else{
            combi[x] = B2[d];
            cout<<"combi[x] = "<<combi[x]<<endl;
            d++;
        }
        x++;
    }
    while(c < one){
        combi[x] = B1[c];
        x++;
        c++;
    }
    while(d < two){
        combi[x] = B2[d];
        x++;
        d++;
    }
    

    cout<<"combi is ";
    for(int f = 0; f<one+two; f++) cout<<combi[f]<<' ';
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    
}

void MergeSort(int *A, int n){
    if (n > 1){
        int *B1 = new int[n/2];
        int *B2 = new int[n - n/2];

        for(int x = 0; x < n/2; x++){B1[x] = A[x];}
        for(int x = 0; x < n - n/2; x++){B2[x] = A[x + n/2];}

        cout<<endl<<"B1 is ";
        for(int x = 0; x < n/2; x++)cout<<B1[x]<<' ';
        cout<<endl<<"B2 is ";

        for(int x = 0; x < n - n/2; x++)cout<<B2[x]<<' ';
        cout<<endl;

        MergeSort(B1, n/2);
        MergeSort(B2, n - n/2);

        Merge(A, B1, n/2, B2, n - n/2);
    }
}

int main() {
    int A[ ] = {4,2,6,1};
    MergeSort(A, 4);
    cout<<endl<<endl<<"final A: "<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) cout << A[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
B1 is 4 2 
B2 is 6 1 

B1 is 4 
B2 is 2 
B1[C] 4 B2[d] 2
combi[x] = 2
combi is 2 4 


B1 is 6 
B2 is 1 
B1[C] 6 B2[d] 1
combi[x] = 1
combi is 1 6 

B1[C] 4 B2[d] 6
combi[x] = 4
B1[C] 2 B2[d] 6
combi[x] = 2
combi is 4 2 6 1 



final A: 
4 2 6 1
```

As you can see, the code runs smoothly at the start, sorting 4 2 and 6 1. However, it seems this sort is only temporary as when B1 and B2 try to combine afterwards, they end up becoming the same numbers as before. Does this have something to do with my usage of pointers?

It seems like the code messes up after the "combi is 1 6" line in the output. Does anyone have any idea what is going on and how to fix this?

Comment: Where do you (re)populate the array `A`?

Comment: You have plenty of memory leaks as well, as you allocate temporary arrays but never delete them.

Comment: Besides leaking memory like a sieve leaks rainwater, you never actually modify the passed in `A`.

Comment: your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know: Why do you expect `A` to hold the elements in different order after the call to `MergeSort`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a problem with `Merge`. At the entrance to the function you expect that the array after merging will be written in argument `A`, but in reality it is written in the local variable `combi`, which you do not use anywhere, and accordingly it does not affect the result

To solve this problem simply in the `Merge` function replace each call of the variable `combi` in call `A`.

The result should be something like this.
**NOTE**: I also added freeing memory, but in general I haven't made code cleaner

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void Merge(int *A, int *B1, int one, int *B2, int two){
    int c = 0, d = 0, x=0;
    while(c < one && d < two){
        cout<<"B1[C] "<<B1[c]<<" B2[d] "<<B2[d]<<endl;
        if(B1[c] < B2[d]){
            A[x] = B1[c];
            cout<<"combi[x] = "<<A[x]<<endl;
            c++;
        }
        else{
            A[x] = B2[d];
            cout<<"combi[x] = "<<A[x]<<endl;
            d++;
        }
        x++;
    }
    while(c < one){
        A[x] = B1[c];
        x++;
        c++;
    }
    while(d < two){
        A[x] = B2[d];
        x++;
        d++;
    }
    

    cout<<"combi is ";
    for(int f = 0; f<one+two; f++) cout<<A[f]<<' ';
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    
}

void MergeSort(int *A, int n){
    if (n > 1){
        int *B1 = new int[n/2];
        int *B2 = new int[n - n/2];

        for(int x = 0; x < n/2; x++){B1[x] = A[x];}
        for(int x = 0; x < n - n/2; x++){B2[x] = A[x + n/2];}

        cout<<endl<<"B1 is ";
        for(int x = 0; x < n/2; x++)cout<<B1[x]<<' ';
        cout<<endl<<"B2 is ";

        for(int x = 0; x < n - n/2; x++)cout<<B2[x]<<' ';
        cout<<endl;

        MergeSort(B1, n/2);
        MergeSort(B2, n - n/2);

        Merge(A, B1, n/2, B2, n - n/2);

        delete[] B1;
        delete[] B2;
    }
}

int main() {
    int A[ ] = {4,2,6,1};
    MergeSort(A, 4);
    cout<<endl<<endl<<"final A: "<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) cout << A[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

**P.S.** If it is available in your case, you should switch your code from raw pointers to [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), from own `Merge` function to [`std::merge`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge), from copying arrays elements by elements to [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: May I ask why is it necessary to add 

"delete[] B1
delete[] B2"

if i have already declared them each time to be "new int"?

Comment: @miloovann ```new``` operator allocates array somewhere in memory, and this memory won't deallocate unless you deallocate it with ```delete``` operator or by canceling your process. So, if your process should always be on, and you have ```new``` without ```delete```, then after a while the amount of allocated memory that is not in use may exceed the amount of memory allowed on the device, and accordingly your program will not work properly. [read more](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/103864/) or google: memory leaks